# List of Swift Global functions

Tags: swift, function, scope

Is there an updated list of Swift global functions? That is, functions that can be accessed from anywhere without the scope of a specific type, like `max()`,`min()`,`dump()`, `zip()`, `sequence()`, etc.

On the Apple docs the nearest link I found out is [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/global-numeric-functions?changes=_3), but it only refers min and max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building project documentation in docC by default all the global functions for a particular module are grouped under `Functions` section similar to `Protocols` section for protocols etc. Apple has customized this behavior so that global functions are grouped in different sections depending on their usage topic. Right now there is no way to list all of the global functions, you have to find them one by one manually. However, there is some work going on to implement [fuzzy search on docC documentations](https://forums.swift.org/t/quick-navigation-in-docc-render/55942/7) to search using certain type of symbols etc.

Comment: Thanks Soumya , it seems that the same question was also asked here: https://forums.swift.org/t/where-to-find-list-of-all-swift-global-functions-such-as-min-max-repeatelement-sequence-etc/53469 . There is a list  out of date (for 4.2) at https://swiftdoc.org/v4.2/func/  . Also autocompleting Swift. can be useful.